# [mysql]Best way to query records from years ago

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, rdbms

Let's say I have a table, the records are stored in this table from years. The amount of data saved is really huge.
And my logic is I need to check current year is exist any records or not. If not I have to move to another year to check, if data has existed, I have to query and return the result.

For Example:

- 2020 -> check -> not exist data, continue check 2019
- 2019 -> check -> not exist data, continue check 2018
- 2018 -> check -> existed data ->
  return records in pagination (Maybe I will query from 0 -> 50, 51
  ->100, ... for better performance)

So, what is the best way to deal with this problem? I don't want to use COUNT to check data has existed or not. You can consider this problem is related to big data, and I hope you can explain a good solution. Thank you so much

The table is as follow:

id

action_type

description

created_at (2020, 2019, 2018....)

updated_at (2020, 2019, 2018....)

created_by

updated_by

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: For example: check 2020 -> not exist data -> continue check 2019 -> not exist data -> check 2018 -> exist data -> return data of 2018

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Comment: "Really huge" means over a billion rows; is that what you mean?  Is each year in a separate table; if so, that is probably a bad schema design.

Comment: Sorry for making confusion. Each year is not separate into multiple tables.  All record are stored in only one table

Comment: Is the query the same each time? Are there many variations of the query? If there is only one query or a few of them i would have a job that would check the big tables and save info about what exists in each table. Maybe a table with which action_type's exist in each year? Even if that will be 1000 rows you can query that fast and then go straight to the correct table.

Comment: @MrApnea I assume I have a table with 7 billion records stored from 2000 to 2020. The record I want to retrieve is stored from 2001. So what is the best way to retrieve that record from 7 billion? May we need to index some fields?

Comment: @user3735175 A bit late answer... but yes you would absolutely need to index. Index on the fields needed to find that specific row. The more unique the better. But it might be a good ide to split that table into smaller ones. But as always it always depends on the data and how it is being used.